# SQL Query with Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have a table with User Information, a table with Client information, and a table with FTP information. I need to join all three tables and then select the records in the FTP table that match all Active users in the User table. The Client table and the User Table contain a client ID and the Client name has a corresponding name.  I need the final results of the SQL query to provide the Client Name, the User Name, and the FTP directory.

*Clients*

```
ClientCode
ClientName
Status
```

*UsersAdminSFTDirectory*

```
IndexNo
UserName REFERENCES Users(UserName)
AccessDir
```

*UsersAdmin*

```
us_ID
UserName
Status
ClientCode
```

Here is what I have so far.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT C.ClientName, 
       UASD.username,
       UA.emailaddress
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT userName FROM UsersAdminSFTDirectory
) AS UASD
JOIN UsersAdmin AS UA ON UASD.username = UA.username
JOIN Clients AS C ON UA.clientCode = C.clientCode
WHERE c.ClientName LIKE '%'
```

Comment: Side note...remove `WHERE c.ClientName LIKE '%'` it will always be true and is a pointless comparison.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We can help but we need some more details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: The Users table has columns for Password, User ID (username), Status.

Comment: The Users table has columns for Password, User ID (username), Status.
The Client table has columns for ClientCode, ClientName, Status.
The SFT table has columns for IndexNO, username, accessdir.
The username in the SFT table and in the Users table should match for this query.

Comment: Clients table:
clientCode, clientName, Status

SFT Table:
indexno, username, AccessDir

Comment: Users table:
us_ID, userName, Status, ClientCode

Comment: You just gave three table names: `Users`, `Clients` and `SFT`  but in the query they are `UsersAdmin`, `Clients` and `UsersAdminSFTDirectory`. Can we assume that those are the same tables, respectively?

Comment: yes, sorry, those are the same. So Users is UsersAdmin, Clients is Clients and SFT is UsersAdminSFTDirectory.

Comment: I have the following code working but it appears to product duplicates which I don't want.


    'select u.username, c.clientname as 'primary', uasd.username,c.clientName as 'secondary'

    from UsersAdmin U, UsersAdminSecondaryClientCodes UASD, clients C

    where 

    u.username = UASD.username
    order by 1, 2'

Answer (score 0):

From your description I think the following query would produce what you want. Note that if users have multiple FTP sites then there will be multiple rows for each user.

```
Select u.UserName,
    u.EmailAddress,
    c.ClientName,
    UASD.AccessDir
  From UsersAdmin As u
  Join Clients As c On u.ClientCode = c.ClientCode
  Join (Select Distinct UserName, AccessDir From UsersAdminSFTDirectory) As UASD
    On u.UserName = UASD.UserName;
```

You also mentioned 'all Active users in the user table' so you might want to add a `WHERE u.Status = 'Active'` or something like that.